# Why is Typescript complaining about json import?

Tags: typescript

global.d.ts

```
type JsonPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null
interface JsonMap extends Record<string, JsonPrimitive | JsonArray | JsonMap> {}
interface JsonArray extends Array<JsonPrimitive | JsonArray | JsonMap> {}
type Json = JsonPrimitive | JsonMap | JsonArray

declare module '*.json' {
  const value: Json
  export default value
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

`import MyContract from '../contracts/EthText.json'`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ "42": { events: { "0x1bccc3454ee2f8d073c40996dc3f4abfdcd8463b2bf39fedb02dcc96bc30be59": { anonymous: boolean; inputs: { indexed: boolean; internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; name: string; type: string; }; "0x2db4e42c3a3196ede5db63d119feacf0dd04ca1fb52c1a93c3ccea03d73b388f": { ...; }; }; links: {...'.ts(7053)
```

Why is Typescript complaining about json import?

Comment: Try enabling the compiler option "resolveJsonModule".

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work.